# Custom rake produces error: rake aborted! Don't know how to build task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, rake, rvm

I'm trying to test a simple rake task (below) but i keep getting the error message: `rake aborted! Don't know how to build task`.

**lib/tasks/scrape.rake**

```
task scrape_bbc: :environment do

  @request = HTTParty.get("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml")

  @html = Nokogiri::HTML(@request)
  @html.css("#item ul li")[0..4].each do |link|

   puts link.text

  end

end
```

The trace for the error is:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for #<HTTParty::Response:0x007fbcc4fb6430>
/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails414/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty/response.rb:66:in `method_missing'
/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails414/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/html/document.rb:255:in `detect_encoding'
/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails414/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/html/document.rb:201:in `parse'
/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails414/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/html.rb:15:in `HTML'
/Users/James/Projects/colate/lib/tasks/scrape.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails414/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails414/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => scrape_bbc
```

Comment: run rake task with `--trace` option and put log here.

Comment: the full trace is above ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri is expecting a string containing HTML. You've given it an `HTTParty::Response` object. Giving Nokogiri `@response.body` as an argument instead of just `@response` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is called `scrape_bbc` but you are trying to call it by name `scrape`.

Comment: sorry, you're right, but that was from an earlier attempt, my bad. the actual trace is there now.

Comment: If you edit your question you should add explicit edits, so the original answer is retained. My answer doesn't make any sense at all anymore. Someone who looks at this now or later will be missing the initial context.